# find user control from asp.net static method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my default.aspx i am using the samplectrl.ascx .
Now i want to find the reference for the **samplectrl.ascx** in a static method.

How can we do this

I have tried like this

```
  Public Shared Function TestMethod() As Boolean
    Dim WebUserControl1 As samplectrl= DirectCast(FindControl("samplectrlname"), samplectrl)        
End Function
```

inside  the static method 
but it throws error in compile time as shown below

> Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared
>   method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of
>   the class

I want to refer from static method..
 how can we do this

Answer (score 1):

you can't access a page control in a shared method.

change it to

```
Public Function TestMethod() As Boolean
    Dim WebUserControl1 As samplectrl= DirectCast(FindControl("samplectrlname"), samplectrl)        
End Function
```